# Configuring IBM MQ with WSO2 EI JMS Inbound Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to configure a JMS Inbound Endpoint connecting to IBM MQ. But on deployment, we are getting a “java.lang.ClassCastException”.

Below are the details of the configurations done.

**Pre-requisites**
1. Copied the wmq-client-8.0.0.4.jar file to the /dropins directory.
2. Copied the jta_1.1_1.0.0.jar file to the /lib directory.
3. Removed following line from the /conf/etc/launch.ini file: javax.jms,\
4. .bindings placed at C:\jndidirectory
5. Started WSO2 EI Server.

**Created JMS Inbound Endpoint as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="ibm-inbound" onError="common_error_handler" protocol="jms" sequence="online-seq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">10</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">MYQUEUE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">3</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">HAQU1</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">file:///C:/jndidirectory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName">user</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Password">password</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/json</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SharedSubscription">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ResetConnectionOnPollingSuspension">true</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

**On deploying CAR we are getting error as below.**
*org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error initializing inbound endpoint rm-to-ec-online-inbound

        at org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint.init(InboundEndpoint.java:83)

        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.InboundEndpointDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(InboundEndpointDeployer.java:57)

        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:197)

        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1065)

        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:106)

        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)

        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)

        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)

        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)

        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)

        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)

        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*
***Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory***
        *at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.factory.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:187)

        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.factory.JMSConnectionFactory.(JMSConnectionFactory.java:164)

        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.factory.CachedJMSConnectionFactory.(CachedJMSConnectionFactory.java:38)

        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.JMSPollingConsumer.(JMSPollingConsumer.java:78)

        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.JMSProcessor.init(JMSProcessor.java:89)

        at org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint.init(InboundEndpoint.java:79)

        ... 23 more*

Answer (score 1):

What helped was commenting out the `javax.jms,\` line in %CARBON_HOME%\cont\etc\launch.ini - #9 here https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Configure+with+IBM+WebSphere+MQ